# how to find OS of Mobile generally?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, operating-system, mobile-phones

I could not find out OS of Lot of mobiles? for example MicroMax , Videocon Mobiles in India, they did not give that details in their specification, what os will it have? why they did not give that details? but JVMs are there...any help please?

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer. In what context are you trying to find out this operating system? From a web page?

Comment: i mean device OS like Symbian,Nokia series...

Comment: I guess you want to do that without programatically... Please clarify...

Answer (score 0):

different brand phones might run on different mobile phone OS and the commands to find the OS might differ under each SDK. How ever if you want to just find under which os the JVM runs u can try these lines

```
try{
      String osName= System.getProperty("os.name");
      System.out.println("Operating system name =>"+ osName);
    }
catch (Exception e)
   {
      System.out.println("Exception caught ="+e.getMessage());          
   }
```

http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/get-OS-name.shtml

Comment: how can I find through this code , for China Mobiles and Micro max,videocon,Lava etc...

Comment: I am not sure if you want to find the OS programmatically or just want to check mobile OS version. If you are able to compile and run a java program on a device that has a JVM then the above lines of code should give you the OS in which Java runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [www.handsetdetection.com](http://www.handsetdetection.com) to detect the Mobile OS & Browser from the HTTP headers. There's about 50k mobile phones, growing at 100 or so per day.

Comment: did u see OS information of VIDEOCON Mobile?i saw except os name...?

Answer (score 0):

http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

It's pretty lightweight, and covers everything without identifying each and every model of device.